# Indicator for Changes Made

Tags: conditional-statements, stata

Is there a way in Stata to execute a piece of code if and only if a previous bit of code actually made changes?

For example, I am concatenating two variables only if one of them meets a `regexm()` test. I understand that if I run this qualifier as an `if` command, it only looks at the first observation. Is there a way to run an `if` command, say

```
if regexm(var`n', ".*\)$") {
   // code
}
```

and have the `if` statement return true if the conditional is true for *any* observation, not just the first one?

Comment: Edited STATA to Stata. I made this edit in your previous thread and trusted that you would notice. The spelling STATA hasn't been used by the company for >30 years. I don't know where the meme STATA comes from now unless it's a spurious analogy with SAS and SPSS. Stata was never an acronym, always an invented name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a match in any observation to trigger code, you need to count matches first:

```
count if regexm(var`n', ".*\)$") 

if r(N) > 0 {
   // code
}
```

`if r(N)` would suffice here, as non-zero arguments are treated as true and `r(N)` from `count` can never be negative.

Comment: I think you're looking for a parenthesis at the end of a string. Another condition for that is `substr(whatever, -1, 1) == ")"`.